# How do I force Maven to wait for all modules in parallel to finish running?

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, maven-3, multi-module

I’m using Maven 3.2.3.  I am running a multi-module project, which contains

```
    <modules>
            <module>module-A</module>
            <module>module-B</module>
            …
            <module>module-X</module>
    </modules>
```

If I run “mvn clean install -T 2”, the modules “module-A” and “module-B” will run in parallel because there is no dependency between either.  However, I’m noticing that if module-B fails while module-A is still running, execution stops altogether and the result of “module-A” is reported as “SKIPPED”.  How do I force Maven execution to not halt until all the currently running modules are finished (in my case, it's a big problem that module-A aborts halfway through).

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Do you have to run them in parallel? What's the problem if the build aborts in the middle?

Comment: Did you try `mvn --fail-at-end`?